# How to check one string contains another sub string in dart/flutter

Tags: regex, flutter, dart

I want to check weather a String contains or not a specific substring in dart/flutter.

example

```
String mainString = "toyota allion 260 2010";
String substring = "allion";
```

I want to check weather substring is in the mainString or not?

Please help me to find a solution

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
String mainString = "toyota allion 260 2010";
String substring = "allion";

mainString.contains(substring); //return true if contains
```